# installing mod_headers on Linux, apache 2.2.21

Tags: apache, mod-headers

Trying to install the mod_headers to be able to append a HTTP header with the Header directive.  But the installation process doesn't show the header module as being installed.

Did the following steps.  Switched over to the httpd installation and under the modules/metadata directory did:

```
 apxs -c mod_headers.c
```

the so file is created under the metadata/.libs directory (not sure why).  Added the module with:

```
 apxs -i -a -n mod_headers ./metadata/.libs/mod_headers.so
```

Restarted apache and tried a dump of the modules but getting:

```
 httpd: Syntax error on line 54 of /www/fkwiki/apache/conf/httpd.conf: Can't locate API module structure `mod_headers' in file /www/fkwiki/apache/modules/mod_headers.so: /www/fkwiki/apache/modules/mod_headers.so: undefined symbol: mod_headers
```

Got a warning in the installation of the module (i.e. apxs -i ....):

```
 Warning!  dlname not found in /www/fkwiki/apache/modules/mod_headers.so
```

Anybody else have the same problem?

Comment: Turns out if I have "LoadModule headers_module     modules/mod_headers.so" rather than "mod_headers_module" it works.